# Define a function without using the fact that it is in Show class

Tags: haskell

Not using the fact that the *Integer* type belongs to the *Show* class define a function

```
integerTostring :: Integer -> String
```

Hint: use the function

```
unfoldr :: (b-> Maybe(a,b))->b->[a])
```

from the *List* module, defined by the formula

```
unfoldr f b=
            case f b of
                  Nothing -> []
                  Just (a,b) -> a : unfoldr f b



where
**data Maybe a = Nothing| Just a deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)**
```

The *Char* module exports the function

```
intToDigit :: Int -> Char
```

the standard prelude offers the following method of the class *Enum*:

```
fromEnum :: (Enum a) => a -> Int
```

and the *Integer* type belongs to the *Enum* class...

What I did is:

```
   import List, Char
    integerToString :: Integer -> String
    integerToString = reverse.unfoldr(\a -> if a>0 then Just(IntToDigit$fromEnum$a'mod'10,a'div'10)else Nothing
```

Is that what i had to do? if not then what to do ?

Comment: The easiest way to tell whether you got it or not, is to just try it out in the interpreter.

Comment: If you are in doubt about the requirements of an assignment, it's best to consult with the one who will grade it.

Comment: If you would alter your condition |if a>0| you could also handle negative values.

Comment: Wouldn't want you to cheat, but the Haskell [Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/numeric.html) has showInt which "extends" showIntAtBase. Pretty solid math, but mostly out of scope for you. Now, if you want to see some insane arithmetic, check out showFloat.

Comment: integerToString == flip replicate $ "1"  -- Base 1

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's a good solution, although you forgot to handle negative integers and 0. Also, I suggest using the `divMod` function instead of using `div` and `mod` seperately.